# How to unit test helper methods in Python scheduled job?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've read quite a few answers on here about testing helper methods (not necessarily private) in my unit tests and I'm still not quite sure what the best approach should be for my current situation.

I currently have a block of logic that runs as a scheduled job. It does a number of mostly related things like update local repositories, convert file types, commit these to other repos, clean up old repos, etc. I need all of this code to run in a specific order, so rather than setting a bunch of scheduled jobs, I took a lot of these small methods and put them into one large method that would enforce the order in which the code is run:

```
def mainJob():
    sync_repos()
    convert_files()
    commit_changes()
```

and so on. Now I'm not sure how to write my tests for this thing. It's frustrating to test the entire `mainJob()` function because it does so many things and is really more of a reliability feature anyway. I see a lot of people saying I should only test the public interface, but I worry that there will potentially be code that isn't directly verified.

Comment: As you have found out, unit testing will pick out design issues arising from tightly coupled code, as this form of testing does heavily skew towards code that are individual units that exposes public interfaces. Those are essentially what you need to test, at the very least make sure all code paths are covered (via coverage checking), then implement the management class that runs things in order and test that those orders are obeyed, and finally wrap it all up with an integration test if needed.

Comment: I also am unsure what I should do about mocking in this case. These functions are making actual changes to a file system, so it's not like I can just mock an object. Maybe I could use a StringIO object to represent open files. It's just a tricky situation.

Comment: StringIO for mocking writing to the file system is a good option. Also, mock actually supports mocking open with a [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open). Which is also another great option.

Comment: Mocking is a very good option considering you mentioned that you are touching several external systems. You probably don't want your tests to have to affect them.

Comment: Yeah, I think what I'm going to wind up doing is changing my wrapper implementation a bit so that it passes `open` objects to the helper methods. This will translate easily over to mocking in the tests. I have a few self contained functions that just check and build directories, so I think for that I'll mock the database so they work with test data, and I'll create a separate set of test directories that `putUp` and `tearDown` at the beginning and end of the test so nothing real gets touched.